# Netbeans does not suggest java.sql.Connection to import

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a newbie in java. I try to create a connection in netbeans. However when I define

> Connection conn = null;

Netbeans does not suggest to import java.sql.Connection library.

Anyone could help me to resolve it. Thank all of you.
I tried

[Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKogj.png)

Comment: @luckyday - what lib would that be? `java.sql.Connection` itself is part of JDK isn't it?

Comment: I don't know why, but I end up (in frustration) just adding `import java.sql.*;` to the top of the file

Comment: Do you have a class of your own called `Connection`? If so, don't.